# Starting TDD halfway a project, good practice?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I am halfway in the development of a large Flask web application.

Back in the beginning I chose not to use test-driven-development, for learning curve vs project deadline reasons.

Thus these last weeks I had the opportunity to learn more about it, and I am quite exited about starting to use it.

However, regarding I didn't wrap my project with TDD from the start, is there any cons of starting to use it now ?

I would not refactor my entire app, only the new features I am going to design in the near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  This is actually a great time to get into unit testing, because your project has already been started.

Often times when beginning a project the technical requirements aren't very solid and there is lots of hands on experimentation with implementations.  During this period unit tests may incur a lot of time overhead.  If technical specifications are not very solid than higher level tests are often way more valuable.  These can include sending a test request through a public interface (the same one a client will use) and broadly asserting on the response/data/etc.  This allows the implementation of the service to change underneath the higher level tests.

The one issue that I can think of with starting later is around the goal of unit testing.  For me, unit testing is primarily a tool for learning how to write testable code, ie coupling, abstraction, encapsulation, [seams](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) etc.  If you're not practiced at writing this sort of code then an opportunity to learn has been missed!

If you have no test harness setup there will be overhead to creating a directory structure, test hierarchy, incorporating your test runner, test coverage/result reporting (xml), test runner integration.  If you're able, hosted services like travis will really reduce the effort involved into incorporating this into your dev process.

Answer (score 3):

TDD "done right" is always good practice - no matter at which point in time you start using it.

But in order to avoid getting to a situation where one part of the code base is nicely unit-tested and others are not: look for ways to not only cover new features. In other words: if time allows don't only test those parts of a file/class that a new feature will go into - but instead try to get that *whole* unit into "tests".

The *core* aspect of unit tests is that they allow you to make changes to your code base without breaking things. Unit tests enable you to go with higher speed. Thus look for ways to ensure that you can go with "high speed" for the majority of your code base.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. **Yes**, you can start using TDD at every single point of development.

When you try the '*red line*' tests which should fall **at the beginning** there is no surprise for you that they show up lack of functionality.

When you start **implementing TDD on the big system** with a huge amount of code already in you should check first for some functionality availability by also writing the test (or the group of tests). Then if it works well you carry on until the test start showing up the limits of code's potential.

Would add that if you start now and decide to cover not only the new features (but the old ones as well as mentioned above) at this point you more likely will spend more time for the old features.

And in that case it would not be called pure TDD (just saying) since some tests is going to be implemented after the code has been written but if it's suitable for the project that's also the option (definitely could worth it). And still it's most likely better to test something now than on the beta-testing stage. At least because it will be easier to come across the solution if you find something is going wrong with your old features.

So later you test so harder it's getting to solve the issues. It takes more time then. And if the people apply tests long time after the code has been written it comes to the double work since you need to rethink how your code works. That`s why in the TDD writing the tests goes almost along with writing the code. Even at this point it's probably easier for you to remember what you were coding at the beginning.